# Can't remove the black background of a relative layout contains a listView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-relativelayout

I'm implementing a custom Dialog which inflates a `RelativeLayout` xml file

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/common_image_list_panel_transparent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/teamListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@drawable/common_team_list_view_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" >
</ListView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cancelTeamDialogButton"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/create_incident_screen_map_overlay_image_close"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|fill_horizontal|center_vertical|fill_vertical"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to change the background color of the `RelativeLayout` and the `ListView` but nothing happens. I always get this [image]

I've already removed the background border of the dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
    new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)));
```

The background image is a png with a frame and the rest is transparent and I positioned the `ListView` inside the frame.
what i want is removing the black color from the background which present in side the frame and outside around the rounded corners of the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using AlertDialog instead of Dialog

Answer (score 2):

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

These two lines will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attributes to the ListView:

```
<android:listSelector = "@android:color/transparent"/>
<android:drawSelectorOnTop = "true"/>
```

Edit:
With the previous attributes added to the ListView, then you can put a white background to the Relative Layout, by adding this to it:

```
<android:background = "@android:color/white"/>
```

Comment: this allowed me to view the list view and make it appear ,, but i don't want the background to be white i want it to be transparent especially the small area around the rounded corners, i want to the dialog to appear as the frame in the png image with no borders or colors around

Comment: Remove the background color from the RelativeLayout. Is that not enough?

Comment: removing the background color or setting is as transparent gives me the same screen shot in my question. any other color works good but i don't want any color to apear

Comment: what background do you want in the dialog?

Comment: i want transparent background, clear area around the rounded corners with no border or any color. i need to dialog appear as if it the png file with nothing around

Comment: i realized that i'm using AlertDialog instead of Dialog that was the problem